# Usage of "Advanced"

Tags: word-usage

I am not a native English speaker. So pardon me for my ignorance. One of my friend sent me a mail saying "Advanced Birthday Wishes". I think the usage of Advanced is incorrect in this context and it should be "Birthday Wishes in Advance".

Is it correct to use "advanced" to indicate some thing that is prior to a point of time? I checked a dictionary but didn't get this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Advanced birthday wishes* is wrong, but *advance birthday wishes* is correct. *[Advance](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/advance_3)* here is an adjective meaning *given before the time it is due*.